# How to get Data Mask to handle deleted fields?

Tags: salesforce-data-mask

We have a data mask configuration set up to mask Opportunity.License_Number__c. We then deleted that field in production (a dependency on Data Mask did not show up).

When we run the data mask configuration in our sandbox, we get this error:

```
No such column 'License_Number__c' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. Line: 205
```

When editing the Data Mask configuration in the sandbox, we don't see any reference to License_Number__c. I tried re-saving the configuration, but that didn't fix the problem. I tried cloning the configuration, but I can't clone with this message in the console:

```
"Cannot deploy metadata with duplicate fullName datamask__Masking_Field__mdt.ACH_Bank_NamecOpportunityNew for entities of type: CustomMetadata"
```

Creating a new configuration will be time consuming and error prone because of the number of fields we're masking.

Is there a way, when deleting a field, to remove it from a Data Mask configuration or prevent the deletion until the dependency is resolved? Is there a way to remove a deleted field from a configuration after it's been deleted? And is this a bug (how do we log that?) or an "Idea"?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should open a support case with Salesforce.